# Error with ActiveAdmin Editor Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup ActiveAdmin Editor on my Rails 4 application. I use the gem and followed the instructions here: https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor , but I'm getting this error:

> NoMethodError in Admin::Posts#new
>
> undefined method `title' for #< Post id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Followed by:

> insert_tag renderer_for(:new)

Did some research and it was suggested for change f.buttons to f.actions, but this won't solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your posts table doesn't have a title column, so either you need to create a migration for it:

```
$ rails g migration add_title_to_posts title:string && rake db:migrate
```

Or perhaps you're following the example from the gem instructions, so you need to remove the following line if you have it in your `admin/post.rb`

```
f.input :title
```

Comment: Yes, after I post it, I noticed that something was wrong with the migration. Currently working on it, I will post results with the ActiveAdmin Editor issue. Thanks.